# How can i get the key and value from an object without a for loop?

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a better way of getting key and value of an object? I am trying to do this without a `for` loop.

```
obj = { collection: 'foo' }

for key, value of obj
  console.log key, value
```

If an object has one key with one value I thought there could be a more efficient way of doing this. I could be wrong though.

Comment: What's wrong with a `for` loop?

Comment: if an object has one key with one value i thought there could be a more efficient way of doing this. i could be wrong though.

Comment: `for..in` is the most efficient way to discover object keys in JS, other than `Object.keys()`.

Comment: The comment changes the question from something odd and possibly pointless into something a bit more interesting so I merged it into the question and reversed my voting.

Comment: browser or node.js? If you are on node.js or rely on the user to have decent browser you could use `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check if an object has exactly one key then you could use a short circuiting loop:

```
exactly_one = (obj) ->
    return false if(!obj)
    how_many = 0
    for own key of obj
        break if(++how_many == 2)
    how_many == 1
```

The basic idea is to use a `for ... of` (i.e. JavaScript's `for ... in`) loop to start counting the number of keys in the object. There are only three cases that we care about:

1. There are fewer than one key (i.e. `null` or no keys). The initial `null` check and the `how_many = 0` initialization take care of this.
2. There is exactly one key. In this case the loop will make one pass and `++how_many` will get hit once leaving `how_many == 1`.
3. There are more than one keys. In this case the loop will only make two iterations due to the `break`. We know that we'll get a `false` result as soon as we've encountered the second key so there's no need to keep counting.

That will function will make at most two iterations of the loop. That's still a loop but there's no rule that forces you to run through the whole loop when you don't need to, you can always `break` out early.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qsNMA/

Minor adjustments to the logic would give you "at most one", "at least one", etc.

If you weren't born a C programmer, then you could unroll the logic a little bit:

```
for own key of obj
    ++how_many
    break if(how_many == 2)
```

You could also write it as:

```
(break if(++how_many == 2)) for own key of obj
```

but that's pushing it IMO.

The `own` stuff just adds [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) checks to avoid accidentally grabbing things from the prototype. You probably won't need that but since they really are out to get me, I prefer to err on the side of caution.

There's also [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) but that's not universally supported and it will have to build a whole array when you only care if its length will be 1 or not:

```
exactly_one = (obj) ->
    return false if(!obj)
    Object.keys(obj).length == 1
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aH8wA/